# Reverting multiple commits and merges back to a specific commit without force pushing

Tags: git, github, revert

**The Problem:**

- Remote Repository with ~50 commits that should be reverted back to 1 specific commit (like a git reset --hard "my specific commit")
- commits AND merges in remote
- no force pushing at all

I know I could do git revert -n "my specific commit"..HEAD the problem with that is that it stops at the first merge. passing -m 1 would fix that, but then it stops at non merges.

git reset --hard and force pushing is *NOT* an option. I can't force push on this git host.

**The Situation: (why would I need this)**

- Bad changes in master, so we checkout a new branch and want to build a new build from an old state (from "specific commit") so we can then deploy that build to prod.
- Individual commits are easy to revert but bulk reverting is time consuming, at best I would want to revert lots of commits at once

I know there are lot's of issues around this on here, but I haven't found one with this exact problem and a reasonable solution without force pushing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Use `git read-tree -u <hash>`, followed by making a new commit.

#### Long

Remember that a Git repository is essentially a collection of commits.  Each commit holds a full and complete snapshot of all files—well, all the files that are in that commit, but expressed this way it sounds tautological—plus some *metadata:* the name and email address of the person who made the commit, a timestamp of when they made it, a log message where they explain *why* they made it, and so on.  (One of the crucial pieces of metadata is this commit's *parent* commit's hash ID, but for once we don't have to concern ourselves with this part at all!)

The true name of any given commit is its hash ID.  You can temporarily stick this commit into your work-tree by doing:

```
git checkout <hash-id>
```

but of course that just gets you a "detached HEAD", and when you re-attach your HEAD by doing `git checkout master`, you're back to the broken source code snapshot.

So, each commit represents a snapshot of all files.  You had a snapshot, at some point, that you like, and you want to go back to it—but without actually going directly *to* it with `git checkout <hash>`.  This means that what you want is to make a *new* commit whose snapshot is the same as an existing commit.  There's some good commit with some existing hash ID, and `git checkout <hash>` is ... OK, but you want a *new* commit with a *new* hash ID, that otherwise matches the good one, at the (new) tip of the current branch.  This new commit should have, as its parent, the current commit, just like *any* new commit has the current commit as its parent.

The method outlined in [joanis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54699033/1256452) will work: it compares what's in the selected commit to what's in the current work-tree, and asks you if you'd like to adjust the work-tree to match the selected commit, for each diff-hunk in each file.  Answering "a" says "take all for this file", but that leaves you with the job of putting in a lot of answers, one for each different file.

It's simpler—but flawed—to use a different mode of `git checkout`:

```
git checkout <good-commit-hash> -- .
```

This mode tells `git checkout`: *Don't switch **to** another commit.  Don't change `HEAD` itself in any way!  But **do** go ferret through the Git database to find the file(s) that match the path-specifier `.` that are in the good commit.  For each matching file, take it out of that commit, copy it to my current index, and copy it to my current work-tree.*

If you do this in the top level of your work-tree, *all* files in the good commit will match the path-specifier `.`.  So if you have files `README` and `main.py` in commit `<hash>`, those will replace the `README` and `main.py` in your index, and the `README` and `main.py` in your work-tree.  You'll be ready to commit.

The flaw here is this: **What if you now have a *third* file, say, `bug.txt`, that *isn't* in the good commit you're trying to switch back to?**  To fix that, you must explicitly *remove* any file that is in your current index and work-tree that is *not* in the good commit.

You could manually remove any such files.  Or there may not be any such files, in which case the problem is merely theoretical.  But there is a guaranteed cure, which is harmless if there's no problem.  You can just start with:

```
git rm -r .
```

to remove *everything*.  That removes `bug.txt` *and* `main.py` *and* `README`.  A subsequent `git checkout <good-commit-hash> -- .` *puts back* the good `main.py` and `README`, and `bug.txt` remains removed, so that you are ready to `git commit` the result.

There's a lower-level Git command that does this for you, though, and that's `git read-tree`.  This command isn't really for everyday use,<sup>1</sup> but this is not an everyday problem either.  In this particular case, using:

```
git read-tree -u <good-commit-hash>
```

tells the plumbing command: *Wipe out my current index.  Get the files from the given hash ID and put those into my index instead.  Wherever you removed a file entirely, remove if from my work-tree too.  Wherever you replaced a file, replace it in my work-tree too.*  That is exactly the same result, in terms of files and their contents, that you get with `git rm -r .; git checkout <good-commit-hash> -- .`, except that it is more efficient.

In either case, you are now ready to make a new commit, using the current index contents, which now match the current work-tree contents (except for untracked files, which remain untracked as usual).

---

<sup>1</sup>The `git read-tree` command is really a *plumbing command*, meant for making new fancy front-end commands that do something, well, fancy.  For instance, someone might, someday, write a `git revert-to` command, which just consists of a few status checks followed by `git read-tree -u <hash>` and `git commit`.

Answer (score 4):

```
git reset --hard good_commit_hash
git reset --soft current_commit_hash
git commit
```

will do what you want.

(You can simply use "@{u}" as "current_commit_hash" if the upstream (remote) branch is the place where you want to commit on.)

Short: if you want to do any kind of cleanup in your repository, use git reset. It's kind of swiss army knife.

Comment: This method will also work, and may be easier for many to remember (than the tricky `git read-tree -u` version). Upvoted.

Comment: I forgot: You should add a "git clean -fd" when you're done, because files that had been added since then will lay around untracked after using this method.

Comment: Nice and simple. I like it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git checkout -p <sha1>` to revert the working tree to a given sha1 without changing where your current branch is.

```
git checkout -p "my specific commit"
```

Answer "a" to each question - I did not find how to force it into a non-interactive variant, although you could use Linux command `yes` - it just types "y" forever:

```
yes | git checkout -p "my specific commit"
```

Then commit and push

```
git commit -m'Reverting to my specific commit'
git push
```

The result is a single commit that undoes the bad history in one fell swoop.

EDIT: **Warning**: If files were removed from `my specific commit` to the current HEAD, this command will not restore them. The solutions proposed by @torek and @Marcus are therefore preferable to this one.

Comment: Easier and arguably better as it removes files that aren't in the other commit: `git read-tree -u <hash>`, followed by `git commit`.

Comment: @torek Not sure what you mean: `checkout -p` also removed files that had been added in between or undid a rename I had in my test sandbox. My tests showed my solution worked well, although I agree yours is more direct and, in the end, simpler. (Is there anything about Git you don't know? I see you answer so many Git questions so reliably well. Thanks for your contribution to Git knowledge on SO!)

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't seen that `git checkout -p` offers to remove entire files. Presumably this means `git add -p` and `git reset -p` do the same—I should test that...

Comment: @torek I would consider any other behaviour from `git checkout -p` a bug. `git reset -p` doesn't seem to handle undoing a rename correctly, however. Darn, I spoke too fast earlier. The rename was only half handled: the new file was removed but the old one was not restored, and `git reset -p` has the same problem. So I take it all back, your solution is the only correct one. And I would argue this is a bug with `reset -p` and `checkout -p`.

Comment: The perl script that implements the patch modes for these three commands has to interpret `git diff` output, and the rename output can be tricky, so that's why I was surprised if it handled it correctly, and am not surprised if it doesn't. :-)